# Xamarin.iOS Ping resulting in System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ping

In my code I'm trying to do the following:

```
Ping ping = new Ping();
var reply = ping.Send(ipAddress);
```

However this always throws a System.InvalidOperationException:

> "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object."

I'm running this on iOS9.1 device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not want to use the Mono Ping routine as it will not work on iOS. Xamarin has wrapped Apple's `SimplePing` sample code into a package/nuget (`Xamarin.SimplePing`).

```
var pinger = new SimplePing("www.apple.com");

pinger.Started += (sender, e) => {
    var endpoint = e.EndPoint;
    pinger.SendPing(null);
};

pinger.ResponseRecieved += (sender, e) => {
    var seq = e.SequenceNumber;
    var packet = e.Packet;
};

pinger.Start();
```

Re: https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/tree/master/iOS/SimplePing

Re: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SimplePing

Comment: NOTE: Xamarin.SimplePing 1.4.1 is not compatible with .Net Standard 2.0.

Comment: @BrettRigby SimplePing uses native iOS/macOS code from Apple and thus was never designed for PCL/.NetStd and thus not cross-platform